# Is there any way to get the location of a point which user touches in a google map without adding google maps in am application?

Tags: android, google-maps

My app needs to receive info about the location a user touches in **Google Maps**.
Is there any way to do following?

1. The user pPresses a button
2. My app calls the Google Maps application (not included in my app, like : Complete action using...)
3. Google Maps returns location info, which my app can then use.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Polaris Maps Library](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=824)

Quoting directly from there:

> Polaris automatically handles essential gestures. The list below gives you an exhaustive catalogue of the available gestures as of version 1.0:
>
> - Single tap on map: opens, if necessary, the callout associated to the    tapped marker
> - Double tap on map: zooms in focusing on the tapped location
> - Long press on map: does nothing by default. Clients may assign a    OnMapViewLongClickListener to the PolarisMapView to be notified of
>   long presses
> - Double tap on map callout: zooms in and pans to the maximum level of    detail available